# Why do I get an error when List<object>.Add(int)

Tags: c#, list, linq, generics

I have an array of List types:

```
List<object>[] vector = new List<object>[3];
```

The first List contains strings:

```
// Get word lists together, remove duplicates
var words = tableA.ToList().Union(tableB.ToList());
// Sort words
words = words.OrderBy(s => s, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
// Add words to the vector first slot
vector[0] = words.ToList<object>();
```

Now, I want to add ints to the second and third lists, but I get an error here:

```
vector[1].Add(tableA.GetValue(keyword));
vector[2].Add(tableB.GetValue(keyword));
```

GetValue() returns an int. But when I add these ints to the vector Lists it throws error:

```
ERROR Caught: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

How should I add the ints to the List? Or is there some other data structure I should use instead for the vector? I feel there is some trivial cast I'm missing but I haven't been able find a solution.

Comment: Does this thing even compile ?

Comment: Yeah it compiled

Comment: List<object> vector = new List<object>[3]; compiles ???

Comment: Oh I forgot the [] when i wrote the question.
List<object>[] vector = new List<object>[3]; **

Comment: -3 for a legitimate question that's stackoverflow for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert in C#, but i think i understand. 
When you write :

```
List<object> vector = new List<object>[3];
```

you create a table of List with a size of 3.
You can put something into each slot of this array, but each "slot" still refers to no instance after this first line of code. 
When you write

```
vector[0] = words.ToList<object>();
```

You put somehting into the first slot of vector list. But [1] and [2] are still empty. And

```
vector[1]
```

refers to *a reference not set to an instance of an object*. In short terms, it refers to nothing.

Comment: So at least set vector[1] & vector[2] to an empty list. For example vector[1] = new List<object>();

Comment: That is correct assumption regards c#. The array has two null values for index 1 and 2.

Comment: List<object> vector = new List<object>[3]; does not even compile.

Comment: Right what Steven said fixed it. Anthansos, it was typo, I think it was still obvious what I was getting at

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize each vector index value before add value. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When writing `var a = new List<object>` you´re only declaring that `a` is a list holding some (in your case three) items. However you don´t determine what stands *in* those three elements. You´d have to out some values into every single item, before you can *anything* with it (e.g. call any method).

You´re allready putting a list into the first item, however the elements on index one and two remain null causing a `NullReferenceException` when calling a method like the following:

```
vector[1].Add(...);
```

So you should initialize the value at index oe and two before:

```
vector[1] = new List<int>();
vector[2] = new List<int>();
```

But still you can´t do much with the list, because it is of type `object`, so you´d have to cast every element to the *actual* type:

```
((List<int>)vector[1]).Add(myInt);
```

Anyway I doubt storing three completely different lists within one single list alltogether is a good idea. Maybe you should define a class with the three lists as members instead:

```
class MyClass
{
    public List<string> Words { get; set; }
    public List<int> NumbersA { get; set; }
    public List<int> NumbersB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No cast necessary that's why i wanted object list. It was just for a single cosine vector similarity calculation so I didn't want to make a whole class for one calculation. But you were right I just needed the two lines: vector[1] = new List<object>(); and vector[2] = new List<object>();.